# is there a way of getting all the keys of the watches in clojure

Tags: clojure

If there was an atom:

```
(def a (atom {}))
```

with the following watches set

```
(add-watch a :watcher println)
(add-watch a :watcher2 println)
```

is there a function like this?

```
(get-watches a)
;; => [:watcher :watcher2]
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`(atom {})` creates an object of type `clojure.lang.Atom` which extends abstract class [clojure.lang.ARef](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/ARef.java) which implements [clojure.lang.IRef](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/IRef.java) interface. IRef declares method [getWatches](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/IRef.java#L21) that is implemented in [ARef](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/ARef.java#L65).

Here's the solution:

```
(def a (atom {}))
(add-watch a :watcher println)
(println (-> a .getWatches keys))
```

It is strange that `clojure.core` doesn't have `get-watches`. Mirroring `add-watch` implementation we get:

```
(defn get-watches 
  "Returns list of keys corresponding to watchers of the reference."
  [^clojure.lang.IRef reference] 
  (keys (.getWatches reference)))
```

Answer (score 4):

Ivan's answer is great for Clojure on the JVM. Here's how you do it in ClojureScript:

`(keys (.-watches a))`

Answer (score 2):

```
(:watches (bean a))
```

or

```
(keys (:watches (bean a)))
```